# Is there a HTML alternative to Prezi?

Tags: webapp-rec, html, html5

Is there a good alternative to [Prezi](http://prezi.com/), besides Google Docs, for slide-based presentations?

I've come across [impress.js](http://bartaz.github.com/impress.js/) and I think it's awesome, but there's no way I can recommend that to a regular user.

Related: how come nobody has made a GUI available for it yet?

Comment: Check [this SitePoint article](http://www.sitepoint.com/5-free-html5-presentation-systems/).

Comment: I found a [comprehensive list of alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/prezi/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time, I'm glad to answer my own question.

[Rvl.io](http://rvl.io) (based on reveal.js) has been launched a few weeks ago and it's great.

[UPDATE] rvl.io is now [slid.es](http://slid.es)

Answer (score 2):

you can try [JessyInk](http://code.google.com/p/jessyink/) - which is now part of Inkscape (opensource). There is an comparison or [Prezi vs. JessyInk](http://people.w3.org/~dom/archives/2009/10/prezi-vs-jessyink/). You can try their showcase presentation - I put a copy of it on my Dropbox [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6066212/JessyInk_1_5_5_showcase.svg).

In discussion they also mentioned [Sozi](http://sozi.baierouge.fr/wiki/en%3awelcome) (also opensource) but I did not try it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Note that [slideshare](http://slideshare.com/) is using HTML5 to display presentations. That means you will need another tool to make presentations in ppt/pdf.

Comment: I'm +1 this cause it's a great product. Not a great alternative to prezi, though.

Answer (score 0):

This might suit your needs: https://github.com/tantaman/Strut It's an authoring tool for impress.js. I'd say it's almost there. Not ready for production yet, but decide for yourself : )

Answer (score -1):

The big(gest?) alternative to Prezi is [SlideRocket](http://www.sliderocket.com/), which is Flash-based (and I think an HTML5 player for non-Flash platforms), but it doesn't support a lot of the creative effects that you can do in Prezi, it's a lot more similar to Powerpoint.

Answer (score -1):

There is another alternative which allows you to build animated presentations: [PowToon](http://www.powtoon.com/)